# Android: Null values are inserted on registration in mysql table

Tags: php, android, mysql

Here's the source code for java:

```
package com.example.entrepreneurexpress;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InvestorRegister extends Activity {

    EditText YourName;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    EditText confirmPassword;
    Button btnClear, btnRegister;

    String nm, emailAdd, cnfPass, pwd, result = null;
    int code;

    InputStream is = null;


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.investors_registration);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        ActionBar aBar = getActionBar();
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        YourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invRegName);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invRegEmail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invRegPassword);
        confirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invRegConfPassword);

        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInvRegRegister);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(
                    (YourName.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
                    (email.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
                    (password.getText().toString().equals(""))
                  ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill In All The Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    nm = YourName.getText().toString();
                    emailAdd = email.getText().toString();
                    pwd = password.getText().toString();

                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(nm, email.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(emailAdd, emailAdd));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(pwd, password.getText().toString()));

                     try{
                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.bijukathemovie.com/insert.php");
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                         is = entity.getContent();

                         Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

                     try{
                         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                         String line = null;
                         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             sb.append(line + "\n");                                
                         }
                         is.close();
                         result=sb.toString();
                     } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                     }

                     try {
                         JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                         CharSequence w = (CharSequence) json_data.get("re");
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once("storescripts/dbconnect.php");

    $name=$_POST['nm'];
    $emailAdd=$_POST['emailAdd'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

    $q="INSERT INTO Investors(invName, invEmail, invPassword) VALUES('".$name."', '".$emailAdd."', '".$pwd."')";
    $s= mysqli_query($con, $q);

    if(!$s) {
        $r["re"]="Inserting problem in database";
        print(json_encode($r));
    } else {
        $r["re"]="Record inserted successfully";
        print(json_encode($r));
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You can see the image [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/5nus5w.jpg)

I am following [this](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/connect-mysql-database-from-android.html) tutorial to do my work. But when I run the application on my device, it work's fine and when crossed checked in the database, i get the NULL values in the database. NULL meaning - there is no entry made in the database. It is blank.

Kindly help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Blank means? No rows inserted or rows with zero length values?

Comment: blank meaning, nothing is displayed in the rows except the id column which is auto_increment.

Comment: OK. Then as I suggested in my answer, did you check and restrict empty values before submit?

Comment: yep.. i did.. but still, null values are inserted..

Comment: Put debug statement in app and server script on the values and see what they really have?

Comment: how to do that ?? actually m new to android n have only little experience with it.

Comment: In the `onClick` method change the first `if` condition. Replace `&&` (double ampersand for AND) with `||` (double pipe for OR).

Comment: And change all `getString()` to `getString().trim()`

Comment: Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `nameValuePairs` you defined

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("invName", 
                                          YourName.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("invEmail", 
                                          email.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("invPassword", 
                                          password.getText().toString()));
```

`BasicNameValuePair` constructor takes parameters

- `name` as name of the query parameter
- `value` as value for the above named parameter

Names you have given are `invName`, `invEmail`, and `invPassword`.

But in your script you are reading query parameters as

```
$name=$_POST['nm'];
$emailAdd=$_POST['emailAdd'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
```

And as `nm`, `emailAdd` and `pwd` as not the names set using `BasicNameValuePair`, reading from `_POST` resulted `NULL`s on them.

And the same are passed to database and hence you see NULL data inserted.

In the app code make changes like this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nm", 
                                          YourName.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailAdd", 
                                          email.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", 
                                          password.getText().toString()));
```

**OR** change your script file to read query params as :

```
$name=$_POST['invName'];
$emailAdd=$_POST['invEmail'];
$pwd=$_POST['invPassword'];
```

And then run your program.

Comment: Still the same after changing back to what you said. Blank values inserted.

Comment: If it was blank then before submitting, check for empty inputs from the text boxes in the app and restrict to submit.

Comment: Nope, still the same.. I have edited the java code, kindly have a look at it.

Comment: In the `onClick` method change the first `if` condition. Replace `&&` (double ampersand for AND) with `||` (double pipe for OR)

Comment: Did you try by changing all `getString()` to `getString().trim()` in the `if` condition?

Comment: yep.. did that also, but still the same.. blank values again. i guess u mean `toString()` right ?

Comment: Before sending to insert statement put and `echo $name` and others. see what it prints?